# Design pattern for web services and users - admin vs token - admin in the name of users or users in their own name

Tags: rest, web-services, security

It is about web service and users (mostly application users).
If the platform supports its own security (ACLs) using LDAP or AD users which pattern is better and why?

1. admin in the name of web service do it all in the name of those users (maybe even link ACLs depending on the user with the object) on that platform with external tables of what user can or cannot do in the platform
2. Web service uses a user token (application user or regular user) and all security is defined in the platform

Are there some patterns about this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the fastest and easiest to have an administrator user who will perform tasks on behalf of technical users or other users.
So, my answer is 1)

Comment: But wouldn't be pattern 2 better, more transparent and more robust?